# <textarea>'s text gets erased in Safari when using jQuery keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

Safari on iPad does not support contenteditable and I don't have control over the generated HTMl. It's for a blog and the default area to insert text is a div with contenteditable attribute. I use jQuery to find this div, hide it, append a textarea and on keyup event for the new textarea put the text into the hidden div and then I can click the Save button and everything gets inserted properly.

The script below works fine in IE, Chrome and FireFox but not in Safari (iPad or PC), why is that and what is the solution?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#defaultBox').parent().hide();

    $('.ms-standardheader').each(function () {
        var test = $(this).html();
        if (test.indexOf("Body") != -1) {
            $(this).parent().parent().after('<tr><td></td><td><textarea id="newBox" style="width:98%; height: 100%;"></textarea></td></tr>');
        }
    });

    $('#newBox').keyup(function () {
        var text = $(this).val();
        $('#defaultBox').text(text);
    });
});
```

Edit: what is happening in Safari is that as soon as I stop typing, the text immediately gets erased in the textarea I type in. The text does not get deleted from the div but it's hard  to see what you wrote since it's hidden.

simple fiddle that works in Safari
http://jsfiddle.net/Va4L2/

I tried with keydown but no difference.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your HTML structure? Where did ".ms-standardheader" come from?

Comment: The div has a dynamic ID in in the form of #ctl00_m_g_cc0fae80_c5f8_428c_9d00_793718f1d202_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField, for now I use the one for that certain blog (I shortened it down to #defaultBox in this example) but to be able to use this script for all blogs I can't use it and need to get a parent element as low as possible in the DOM which is that class. Anyway, the question is why Safari erases the content in #newBox as soon as I stop typing.

Comment: your example on jsfiddle.com works fine in safari on my pc

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote. Updated it now and it still works :/ must be something else along the 1000's lines of H TML/Scripts M$ generates.. http://jsfiddle.net/Va4L2/2/

Comment: changed the textarea to <input type="text" and the entered text does not get deleted. Can't understand why it would make any difference.

Comment: You might be interested to know that iOS 5 will apparently support `contenteditable`